# Java. Broken image from URL

Tags: java, swing, io, javax.imageio

I am trying to load this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/302CL.jpg) from URL, but receive image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnV8Y.jpg).

Code:

```
@Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://s.developers.org.ua/img/announces/java_1.jpg");
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                byte[] b = new byte[512];
                while (in.read(b)!=-1)
                    out.write(b);
                Image img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't read images inside the `paintComponent` method, it will make your application appear sluggish, as the method is executed on the event dispatcher thread (EDT). Also, it will be re-read, whenever your component is re-painted, meaning you'll download the image over and over. Instead, read it up front, or in a separate thread (ie. use a `SwingWorker`), and only invoke `g.drawImage(...)` from inside the `paintComponent` method.
2. The reason for the broken image is your byte copying code, where you don't pay attention to how many bytes are read (as long as the value isn't `-1`), but instead unconditionally copy `512` bytes. However, you don't need to do that here, you can simply pass the stream to `ImageIO.read`, like this, making the code simpler and more readable:

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://s.developers.org.ua/img/announces/java_1.jpg");
   try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())) {
       BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
   }
   ```

   Adding the extra `try` (try-with-resources) block makes sure your stream is also properly closed to avoid resource leaks.
3. For completeness, to fix the byte copying code, the correct version would be:

   ```
   // ... as above ...
   byte[] b = new byte[512];
   int bytesRead; // Keep track of the number of bytes read into 'b'
   while ((bytesRead = in.read(b)) != -1)
       out.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but you might write more than you get.
I suggest that you change your writing code to:

```
int len;
while ((len=in.read(b))!=-1)
    out.write(b, 0, len);
```

Otherwise, if the last buffer is not exactly 512 bytes long, you'll write too much

Answer (score 0):

I have some code copy file from URL to Local.. So far the result is same like actual source. Just do some modification maybe can help to solved it.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImagesUrlToImagesLocal {
    public ArrayList<String> getIt(ArrayList<String> urlFile)
    {
        ArrayList<String> strResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        Image imagesUrl = null;
        String baseName = null;
        String extension = null;
        File outputfile = null;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < urlFile.size(); i++)
            {
                URL url = new URL(urlFile.get(i));
                baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(urlFile.get(i));
                extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(urlFile.get(i));
                imagesUrl = ImageIO.read(url);
                BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) imagesUrl;
                outputfile = new File("temp_images/" + baseName + "." + extension);
                ImageIO.write(image, extension, outputfile);
                strResult.add("temp_images/" + baseName + "." + extension);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return strResult;
    }
}
```